# UITableView detect docking and undocking of section header

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `tableView` with a `viewForHeaderInSection` set to a custom view. What I am trying to accomplish is to change this view to a different view when the header section becomes sticky.

Is there a callback that I can use to detect when the tableView's section header sticks to the top?

Any pointers on this would help greatly, thanks!

Edit:
Adding a mock here to better explain what I am trying to accomplish here.

[image: ![enter image description here]

- My `tableView.tableHeaderView` is set to a "Banner GIF animation" (Black region in the image)
- The section header of the tableView is set to a `UISegmentedControl` which has "Tab 1" & "Tab 2"
- "Image 1" & "Image 2" here are parts of the tableView's cells.

As of now, as you scroll, the black section (tableview's header) scrolls with the screen and goes away as you scroll.

The tableview's section header (ie., Tab1/Tab2) sticks to the top of the screen as you scroll past it.

I want this section to change from `Tab1/Tab2` to a `countdown timer` (similar to header's '10D|4H|3M|03S' view) when section header sticks, and change it back to tabs view when it undocks.

Comment: Did you get it working? I want to implement similar functionality.

Comment: Yes, I ended up using tableView's scroll delegate `scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)` and checking if the `tableView.contentOffset.y` is greater than tableView's header height. If yes,

Comment: thanks..I too got that working ..:)

Comment: @PGDev Can you please provide me with an implementation of this ? I need to implement a similar functionality. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may accomplish that better in scrollViewDidScroll and with a simple calculation of current tableView offset and cell heights you can find whether a specific header is on top and change it's view to another

Comment: I have put `scrollViewDidScroll` in place and I'm able to pinpoint at which `tableView.contentOffset.y` value I want to make the switch, but how do I access tableView's section header from here?

Comment: make a global integer say headerViewSection  and when you find out the section index of the cell which background color needs to be changed reload the table and in viewForHeader set the needed color for that section's header view